# Printing (part of) array in one printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print elements of array using single `printf`. The array is small (for example up to 10 elements), but each time I may have to print different number of first elements of array.

I know I can do this:

```
count = how_many_first_elements_i_need_this_time();
printf("array elements: ");
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
printf("\n");
```

But this may lead to interleaving outputs of several `printf` executed at the same time by different threads, I suppose.

I can write huge switch to handle all possible cases, but it is ugly.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can concat your output and display it at the end

Comment: "But this may lead to interleaving outputs of several printf executed at the same time by different threads, I suppose." - yes, and it wouldn't be different if you used only one call. Thread management disregards function call boundaries.

Comment: If the purpose is very simple, like for logging, then you could print thread-id with array element to track

Comment: I agree with *H2CO3*: In a multithreaded environment, you need to protect the output file (here: `stdout`) against concurrent access, even if you'd print out all array's membere using *one* call to `printf()`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But to be honest, I'm not using `printf` but some kind of linux kernel printer which wraps the phrase I'm providing with some additional data: pid, time, etc., so I BELIEVE it does synchronization. This is the reason I demand single `printf` call.

I have used `printf` to make this question as simple as possible and to be useful for broader range of cases than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the solution is use sprintf

Collect all the output in one char buffer and print the whole string only once.

You can allocate the buffer dynamically...

```
char *pcBuf;
int iLen = 0;
count = how_many_initial_elements_i_need_this_time();
printf("array elements: ");

pcBuf = malloc((count * MAX_SIZE_OF_NUM) + count +1); //+count is required for space, and 1 is required for NULL

for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    iLen += sprintf(pcBuf+iLen, "%d ", array[i]);

printf("%s \n", pcBuf);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no formatting specifier to `printf()` to make it print multiple elements of an array automatically (except `%s`, but that's stretching it).

So, you're going to need to keep the loop.

To make each thread's output more atomic (I'm not sure it's guaranteed that each `printf()` is *truly* atomic) you can build the output in a string buffer which is then printed all at once.

One way of doing that is by using `sprintf()` in a loop:

```
char out[1024], *put = out;

for(i =0; i < count; ++i)
  put += sprintf(put, "%d ", array[i]);
strcat(put, "\n"); /* Fast! */
printf(out);
```

Of course, this can be adjusted to not buffer overflow if there's a risk, but 10 integers in 1,024 characters should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some type of thread sync (if you use pthreads you may have a look at mutexes). A thread then acquires a lock just before the output loop and frees the lock after.

If there is a computation in the loop, this may lead to performance issues since threads will have to wait for each other. If you just output an array i don't expect any performance disadvantages compared to the sprintf solution.